# AAM instruction in 8086

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I am new with 8086 and i need a little help.
I know the basic of AAM.
that if i multiple two no.s suppose 07H and 09H

```
MUL AL,BL
AAM
```

this will store the value 06H in AH and 03H in AL.
But suppose if apply AAM at a value of 3 hexadecimal bits, Suppose

```
MOV AL,77H
MOV BL,0AH
MUL BL
AAM
```

What will be the content of AL at last ?

Comment: Just use a debugger and try it. I get ax = 01d06h for 77*0a and aam, which is not a valid BCD result.

Answer (score 5):

```
AAM (BCD ADJUST AFTER MULTIPLY)
```

> [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-1323/instructionset-55/index.html)
>
> use aam only after executing a mul instruction between two BCD digits
>   (unpacked). mul stores the result in the AX register. The result is
>   less than 100 so it can be contained in the AL register (the low byte
>   of the AX register). aam unpacks the AL result by dividing AL by 10,
>   stores the quotient (most-significant digit) in AH, and stores the
>   remainder (least-significant digit) in AL.

So question is what it will do if we provide `Al` bigger value than `99`?

**It will do the same `AH = AL / 10` and `AL = AL mod 10` but will leave incorrect unpacked bcd values.**

So Coming to your case
 before `AAM`   `AL` will be  `166 (0xA6)`   (`AX` will be `0x04A6`  after multiply)
 after `AAM`

```
  Ah=  166/10=16 ( 0x10)
  AL=166 mod 10=6 (0x6)
```

As we see `AX` will be `0x1006` after `AAM`
And  it left incorrect `unpacked bcd number`. BeCause the input was not below `100`

Comment: Is it ascii adjust or bcd adjust? are both same?

Comment: yes, it could be used interchangeably. but probably "ASCII adjust" fits more to the letter. but still, you need or with 48 ( hex: 30) to get ASCII digit

Answer (score 0):

**ASCII Adjust after Multiplication(AAM)**:

Corrects the result of multiplication of two BCD
values.

**Algorithm**:

AH = AL / 10

AL = remainder

**Example**:

MOV AL, 15 ; // AL = 0Fh

AAM ; // AH = 01, AL = 05

RET